# How do I add the 3 Variable in the last line without getting a Syntax Error?

Tags: python

Cement formula mix is normally 1 part cement, 2 parts sand and 3 parts gravel. Therefore my answer should be Cement + Sandx2 + Gravel x3. How do I add the 3 variables in the last line, without getting a syntax error?

```
Cement = float (input ('Cement available (L): '))
Sand =  float ('Sand required: ' + Cement *2 +  ' L')
Gravel = float ('Gravel required: ' + Cement *3 + ' L')
print ('Concrete produced: ' Cement + Sand + Gravel ' L')
```

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few syntax errors in your code.  Try:

```
cement = float(input('Cement available (L): '))
sand = cement * 2
gravel = cement * 3
print(f'Sand required: {sand} L')
print(f'Gravel required: {gravel} L')
print(f'Concrete produced: {cement + sand + gravel} L')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cement = float (input ('Cement available (L):'))
print('Sand required: ' + str(Cement*2) + 'L','\n','Gravel required: ' + str(Cement*3) + 'L','\n','Concrete produced: ' + str(Cement + Cement*2 + Cement*3) + 'L')
```